# Issue with styling li in carousel navigation

Tags: html, css

I'm working on "Related Articles" widget carousel navigation in WordPress. Widgets is working fine and now I'm working on styling part.

This is what I currently have:

[image]

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

The problem is that I'm stuck on styling `li`. The problem is that I'm trying first of all to add `width` and `height` even with `!important` and it's still not re-sizing. So I need to split this carousel navigation into 8 similar parts. I think `display:inline` / `display:inline-block` might cause this issue.

**CSS:**

```
div.carousel_navigation {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #eeebe7;
    width: 224px;
    position: relative;
    border-right: 1px solid #b1afa9;
    border-left: 1px solid #b1afa9;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b1afa9;
}

ul li.prev-article, ul li.next-article {
    display: inline;
    width: 28px;
    height: 20px;
}

li.nav-item-links {
    display: inline;
    width: 28px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

**PHP:**

```
<div class="carousel_navigation">
    <ul>
        <li class="prev-article"><a class="prev-article">&lt;</a></li>
        <?php $count = 1; foreach( $related_posts_guides as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
            <li class="nav-item-links">
                <a href="#item_<?php echo $count; ?>">
                    <?php echo $count; ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php $count++; endforeach; ?>
        <li class="next-article"><a class="next-article">&gt;</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- .carousel_navigation -->
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your `li` elements are `inline`. If you want them to be in line with eachother, but also stylable with properties like `height` and `width`, you'll need to set them as `inline-block` instead:

```css
ul li.prev-article, ul li.next-article,
li.nav-item-links {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 28px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Note that I've also joined both of your selectors with a comma as their style properties were identical.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I thought it should be very simple to get it.. Obviously I know that trick, I've did it because are separated because they will have different styles :)